# Change .exe file version (from C++ project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exe

I have a C++ project and I want to change the EXE file version by code.

How can I do it?

(I found some ways to do it in other languages, but not C++.)

Comment: You should be able to right-click on the Visual C++ project in Visual Studio and choose "Project Properties", in there there will be a string that allows you to change the file version.

Comment: @ThomasRussell I don't find this property

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Add a *version resource* file to your project

> In Solution Explorer, right click at your project -> Add -> Resource -> Version

2. Change value of *FILEVERSION* key to the value you want